# Complete separable metric space intuition

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In a more advanced type of stochastic theory textbook (with applications in finance), I was searching for some elementary assumptions that are defined in filtering theory. Specifically, the space of the variables of interest is set to be a complete seperable metric space, i.e. a topological space that satisfies the property of compactness according to the notion of a complete seperable space. But I strugle to understand the notion of seperability. From the best of my knowledge:

A topological space is seperable if it contains a countable dense subset. For instance  the real line $\mathbb{R}$ contains the subset of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. I understand that the crucial assumptiomn here is the desne subset, but I strugle to understand the notion of dense sets and seperable sets intuitively. Can someone explain, the whole intuition behind these notions? I only know that $\mathbb{\bar{Q}}=\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: $A \subseteq X$ dense in $X$ intuitively means that no matter where you "zoom" in $X$, you see elements of $A$ lurking around...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comment by @dohmatob is very descriptive and one should keep it in mind. Another way to understand density, is this: topological space is nothing more than a set together with a notion of closeness (that is described by the topology, which is simply a collection of subsets). When a subset $D$ is dense in our space, this means that we can "approximate" any element $x$ of our space by elements of $D$. This is very important because for example there are many properties that are carried out by approximation. Maybe, for example, you can easily prove that the dense set has a specific property and, if this property is carried out by approximation, you actually have proven this for the whole space.